# ios web view code is ok but it didnt open website

Tags: ios

I am trying to open google.com with my webview but although the code has no errors page dont open just blank white screen.I tried the sample codes out there and followed tutorials but always blank white page comes up EVEN with sample codes and I cant solve it I worked with iad's before and they didnt cause me any problem so why is this simple webvies is causing problem please help me !

The webview object is connected to viewcontroller and I am using Xcode 4.3

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;  
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView; 

@end
```

kk

```
@synthesize webView ;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        webview.delegate = self;

        NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.com";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created it in loadView? Since you don't use the interfacebuilder...at least that is what I can tell from the posted code.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad I am adding it under this